# Issue with HTML resizing in email

Tags: html

**Objective**: Write HTML that resizes based on screen size.

- Large screen -> "Desktop" mode (left and right column)
- Small screen -> "Mobile" mode (right column falls below left column)

**Issue**: Whenever I open the html in outlook/gmail (screen size well above 768px), I get the "Mobile" version. I don't know how to fix this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .aside {
        background-color: #7a7a7a;
        padding: 15px;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
    }
    [class*="col-"] {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
    }


    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 50%;}


    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        /* For mobile phones: */
        [class*="col-"] {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="aside">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="aside">
        <p>More text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the client supports media queries - I know a lot of email clients are very basic in what they can understand (eg some can't even handle styles as you have done them - some need inline styles).  This is a good guide: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @KaSkuLL I am not sure. This is primarily going to Microsoft Outlook users, and I know they can be a little difficult when it comes to HTML formatting. Do you have any suggestions when clients do not support media queries?

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem is from `[class*="col-"]`, I've a friend that have a similar problem with his `p[class=redbox]`. Then he wrote `p.redbox` instead and everything was fine. You can try it.

**EDIT**: So it becomes `.col-3{your css}` instead of `[class*="col-"]`

Comment: @user9975267 Sorry for the misunderstanding, he transform p[class=redbox] to p.redbox. So you have to transform your [class*="col-"] too. Is col-3 your only col- class? If yes .col-3 instead of [class*="col-"]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As of now, yes. Col-3 is the only col- class